# CkEditor 5 Angular - Changing list button color

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor 5 in an Angular component as explained in the guide: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

At the buttom of the guide there is a description of how to change the css styling of the editor using:

```
:host ::ng-deep .ck-editor__editable_inline {
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

I have expanded on that to style other colors, but I can't find out how to change the color of the two split parts of the list button, when mouse is hovering over it.

Have anybody experience with changing the colors from inside Angular ?

[Example of the white background, I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGRQ6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.

Using

```
:host ::ng-deep .ck.ck-splitbutton:hover > .ck-splitbutton__arrow:not(:hover)
{
  background-color: red !important;
}
:host ::ng-deep .ck.ck-splitbutton:hover > .ck-splitbutton__action:not(:hover)
{
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

The trick was to download the files from github, and look inside

ckeditor5-master/packages/ckeditor5-theme-lark/theme/ckeditor5-ui/components/button/switchbutton.css

and try to match the styles in there.